# Find max value in List

Tags: java, list

I failed to solve this task. 'I have a `List<Car>` where a car is an object with `carNumber` and `kmPassed` props. Return a `Car` with max `kmPassed` value.' 
I know how to find min/max in array but how to find it in `Car` object?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Great time to read about [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) Interface